# Detect Redis's master db failover and auto switch slave to master?

Tags: windows, redis

I have a master redis db which has **2** slave dbs which were constructed via :

- instance `#1` `slaveof 192.168.1.1 6379`
- instance `#2` `slaveof 192.168.1.1 6379`

**Question**

Is there any setting which accomplish  :

> "When the master has failover , promote instance #2 to be the  master" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Redis Sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) and a Redis client with support for Sentinel.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "Client with support for sentinel" ?